# Can I use a jhipster module to alter existing source in a jhipster application?

Tags: jhipster

I have already created a jhipster module that creates a class, copy class content based on user input parameters.

However, I want to modifythe existing code (especially UI code) in my jhipster app using a module.

For example, I want to change the nav bar elements (not add new, but to change the text of the ones that is already there), change the colors and other UI elements.

Is this possible? I saw many answers that show how this can be done manually. I'm trying to find out how to access the source of the generated app from the module and modify it.

Regards
Awanthika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  For example, in the module [you can import BaseGenerator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-module/blob/6328a1d910cc80f5c62a33250508133ab8368c83/generators/app/templates/generators/app/_index.js#L4), which gives you access to the methods in JHipster's `BaseGenerator` class.

The `BaseGenerator` has a method called [`replaceContent`](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/ca944419e618668afe08367a6ff80b8746f4376f/generators/generator-base.js#L1963-L1988).  You can pass either a string or a regex into the method to replace content in an existing file.  This is how JHipster injects contents into the templates, such as Navbar links to entities.

Comment: can you also point me to the place where jhipster inject content into templates?

Comment: Here's where the menu item is injected above the menu needle in the navbar file https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/ca944419e618668afe08367a6ff80b8746f4376f/generators/generator-base.js#L220